# how to configure route in webapi c#, so that any variable name can be used in place of {id}

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have configured the convention based routing as below in `WebApiConfig.cs`

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DataDictionaryApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { id= RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

This works fine for this api end point.

```
[ActionName("DeleteDataDictionary")]
public void DeleteDataDictionary(int id)
{
    //my code
}
```

But I want to use any meaningful name for the variable instead of id. 
For example:

```
[ActionName("DeleteDataDictionary")]
public void DeleteDataDictionary(int dataDictionaryId)
{
    //my code
}

[ActionName("DeleteMenu")]
public void DeleteMenu(int menuId)
{
    //my code
}
```

The problem is it only works when I give parameter name as id.

Comment: I am not expert on matter but the `{id}` seems like a placeholder and you can use 
any variable in its place have you tried giving in the required parameters to your `ActionName("DeleteMenu/{menuId}")`.

Comment: yes, I tried. but it only accepts what I keep in routeTemplate

Answer (score 0):

Use an attribute routing instead.

```
[Route("api/delete-dictionary/{dataDictionaryId:int}")]
public void DeleteDataDictionary(int dataDictionaryId)
{
    //my code
}
```

And send a request as follows,

```
/api/delete-dictionary/1
```

Comment: But the requirement is not to hard code controller name in route for every api. It should be in {controller} as the convention based routing does. It should be like {controller}/{action}

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [FromRouteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromrouteattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Example:

```
[ActionName("DeleteDataDictionary")]
public void DeleteDataDictionary( [FromRoute("id")] int dataDictionaryId)
{
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I think you're referring to FromRouteAttribute which is supported in asp.net core. But my project is not in .net core. Thanks!